# Finding resistance with function

Tags: functions

The function is given as: $$R(T) = R_{0} (1 + \alpha T)$$
where, $R_{0}$ is the resistance at initial temp 0 degree Celsius,
$\alpha$ is the temperature coefficient
If the initial resistance ($R_{0}$) is 10 I need to find temp at T=0,10,50
considering $\alpha$ is of platinum (0.0038)
Now the problem is that if I put $R_{0}$ as 10 T=0 I can calculate easily but when I need to find $R(T)$ at T=10 what will be $R_{0}$? Will it be same as 10 or it will change? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason for it being called $R_{\color{red}{0}}$-the resistance at $0^\circ$.

(Remember , $R$(resistance) is a function of only $T$, not $R_0$. So the only variable is $T$. )